# std::decimal::decimal64 correct usage, g++ 4.6.3

Tags: c++, floating-point, g++, decimal

I'm investigating the replacing of doubles in our code with g++'s std::decimal::decimal32/64/128 types for purpose of currency amounts and prices, however I'm getting stuck on the point of how to best input and output the data. Specifically, there do not appear to be any routines for converting to/from a string, and the stringstream mechanisms do not compile for these types. The only way I see doing this is to use double as an intermediate type, however surely this at least partially defeats the purpose of using the decimal types if we're always inputting and outputting via doubles?

I'm sure I'm not understanding something here so would welcome some feedback on how best to use these types.

Edit:

I have hacked together a couple of input/output routines, however I'm not really satisfied with either. The input is hardly robust (no scientific notation support) and the output routine is simplistic, not to mention inefficient due to the double conversion.

```
#define MAX_DEC_LEN 17

std::decimal::decimal64 FromString(const char* str)
{
    if (strlen(str) > MAX_DEC_LEN)
        throw std::runtime_error("bad input");
    char buf[MAX_DEC_LEN+1];
    strncpy(buf, str, MAX_DEC_LEN+1);
    char* point(NULL); 
    if ((point = strchr(buf, '.')) != NULL)
        *(point++) = '\0';
    std::decimal::decimal64 ret(atoi(buf));
    if (point != NULL && *point != '\0')
    {
        int exponent(strlen(point));
        long long unsigned coeff(atoi(point));
        std::decimal::decimal64 d2(std::decimal::make_decimal64(coeff, -exponent));
        if (*buf == '-')
            ret -= d2;
        else
            ret += d2;
    }
    return ret;    
}

std::string ToString(std::decimal::decimal64 dec)
{
    double d(std::decimal::decimal_to_double(dec));
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(6) << d;
    return oss.str();
}
```

I'm really after something better for both of these, plus a round (to a particular precision) to round things off (pardon the pun)

Comment: According to this (not sure how reputable it is - it's from 2006), `decimal` should support overloading the stream operators: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n1977.html. Maybe g++ is just not there yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Decimal TR](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2009/n2849.pdf) defines overloads for input and output in sections 3.2.10 and 3.2.11, respectively. From the looks of it they are not implemented by gcc. The decimal support in gcc is implemented in terms of libdecnum which provides routines to convert from and to strings. I would create a simple implementation of the I/O operators using them to get started.

Edit on 2012-10-17: Looking at formatting the decimal values in gcc's library (`std::decimal::decimal64` and family) revealed that gcc unfortunately doesn't install either the decNumber library headers or the library. Furthermore, other sources of [decNumber](http://download.icu-project.org/files/decNumber/) don't quite align with the version shipping with gcc. As a result, the only way I found so far to get decimal numbers formatted is to use explicit declarations and using the library build during compiling gcc.

The simple part is the source, although for a rather simple implementation. First, the declaration which would go into a suitable header, e.g. `<decimal/decimal>`:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, std::decimal::decimal32 const&);
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, std::decimal::decimal64 const&);
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, std::decimal::decimal128 const&);
```

A fairly simple implementation of something doing some formatting, although without any options could look like this:

```
extern "C" char* decimal32ToString(std::decimal::decimal32 const*, char*);
extern "C" char* decimal64ToString(std::decimal::decimal64 const*, char*);
extern "C" char* decimal128ToString(std::decimal::decimal128 const*, char*);

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out,
                          std::decimal::decimal32 const& value)
{
    char buffer[128];
    decimal32ToString(&value, buffer);
    return out << buffer;
}

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out,
                          std::decimal::decimal64 const& value)
{
    char buffer[128];
    decimal64ToString(&value, buffer);
    return out << buffer;
}

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out,
                          std::decimal::decimal128 const& value)
{
    char buffer[128];
    decimal128ToString(&value, buffer);
    return out << buffer;
}
```

With this in place, there is still an issue that I didn't manage to build anything using decimals unless some level of optimization, i.e., `-O1` (or higher), is used. There are unreferenced symbols unless optimization is used but this is entirely unrelated to printing the values. To get definitions of the functions used in the implementation, I needed to link to the `libdecnumber.a` library which is created while gcc is being build:

```
g++ -o prog decimal-io.cpp main.cpp <gcc-build-root>/libdecnumber/libdecnumber.a
```

Aside from this I have my own implementation of the [Decimal TR](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2009/n2849.pdf) with [some extension](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3407.html) and basing it on the decnumber library and implement I/O properly. My implementation hopefully will become publicly available at some point but not any time soon.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds simple enough. However I can't for the life of me work out how to access the libdecnum routines using my gcc compiler (standard gcc 4.6.3 shipped with ubuntu 12.04). Can't find any headers to include. I hope this won't require a special build of gcc ... any idea ?

Comment: I'm looking at the gcc implementation and it is quite interesting although also quite unhelpful for your goal: it doesn't refer to the header from libdecnumber and doesn't install them anywhere! To make matters worse, even when declaring the function manually it doesn't seem to be defined in the used libraries, nor is printing supported for the C extensions. This seems to render the decimal number support relatively useless.

Comment: Given the guarantees on retained digits, it is viable to read a decimal value into a `double` and convert this into a `std::decimal::decimal64` as long as it doesn't use more than 15 decimal digits and printing it by converting back to a `double`. However, this is a waste of CPU cycles. I'll have a closer look at what it takes to get I/O working for decimals.

Comment: Sounds promising! Here's to hoping you can produce something better than my attempt.

Comment: Nice work Dietmar. I also found this on the web, https://launchpad.net/std-decimal, which might suffice until something more complete comes out. This wraps Intel's FP library (http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-decimal-floating-point-math-library/). Seems to work well enough, and has the input/output and rounding (aka quantize) routines that I need.