# _Decimal64 does not have a type in C++

Tags: c++, floating-point, decimal

I am mixing C with C++ source code using GNU. `_Decimal64` is recognised fine in C, but not in C++. C++ complains `error: '_Decimal64' does not name a type`.

Is there any way I can fix this? Should I consider it a compiler bug?

**Update 20-Mar-2017 18:19**:

None of the answers meet my requirements so far. I don't want to use the `decimal64` C++ class, I want to use the `_Decimal64` C type. My project is mostly written in C, but I want to slowly introduce C++ code. Here, for example, is part of `cell.h`:

```
union vals
  {
          num c_n;
          //double c_d;
          char *c_s;
          long c_l;
          int c_i;
          struct rng c_r;
  };
```

It is made use of in `cells.c`, which of course is C code. `num` is defined in `numeric.h`:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef __cplusplus
#define USE_DECIMAL 0
#else
#define USE_DECIMAL 1
#endif

#if USE_DECIMAL
typedef _Decimal64 num;
#define NUM_HUNDREDTH 0.01DL
#define NUM_TEN 10.0DL
#else
typedef double num;
#define NUM_HUNDREDTH 0.01
#define NUM_TEN 10.0
#endif
```

Notice that I have use `typedef double num` to get a compile on the C++ side. C++ doesn't actually `num` type, but it is inevitably included because it needs some of the functionality in the C files.

It's faking it, of course.`num` isn't a double, it's really a `_Decimal64`. I'm asking how I can get around this kludge.

Comment: It looks like it's a GCC `C` extension: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Decimal-Float.html

Comment: @SergeBallesta: Sorry, I mistyped that: I meant to say that "C++ does not contain such a **type**." Ugh.

Comment: @RichardCritten: Yes, you're right, C doesn't contain that type, either, it's just a GCC extension.

Comment: "Should I consider it a compiler bug?" --> C allows "Additional arithmetic types, such as `__int128` or `double double`, ..." C11 §J.5.6

Comment: You cannot mix C and C++ source code. Either you compile as C or C++.

Comment: @Olaf You can mix C and C++ code. I have done it using `extern "C" { ... }`.  This is question is specifically about allowing the interop between C and C++ in the presence of _Decimal64.

Comment: @blippy: `extern "C" tells C++ to use C ABI, not C source code semantics! It is still C++ code. Even if you use identical syntax, semantics of C andd C++ differ. They are not the same language.

Comment: Yes, `_Decimal64` is a GNU C extension. The question is, how can I also use it from GNU C++

Answer (score 1):

For C++ "decimal64"

use `std::decimal::decimal64`

the standard says:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.6/a00454.html

Comment: It's **not** a standard type in C++, still a [TR](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3871.html)

Comment: yes, did you look at the [latest C++ standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/)? It's no where to be found. There's [no update to the decimal TR either](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental) so this terrible answer is still entirely incorrect

Comment: and this is [straight from the `std::decimal` proprosal's author](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14096071/995714)

Answer (score 1):

`_Decimal64` is neither standard C++ nor standard C. It is simply proposed in the [TR 24732 document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1312.pdf).

Ok, gcc supports it at least when compiling C source. The C++ counterpart seems to be [TR 24733](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2009/n2849.pdf). It defines a `std::decimal::decimal64` class.

Those definition are likely to be compatible, because I cannot imagine GCC fellows to build 2 different implementation of the IEE754 decimal floating points, but according to that [other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12865735/3545273) gcc support is still incomplete (at the time of the post, that is 2012).

You must dig in gcc documentation to find more because it is currently implemented as a gcc extension.

Answer (score 1):

We have it in this header file

```
#include <decimal/decimal>
```

and

Use it as `std::decimal::decimal64 var;`

`decimal` `namespace` is in `namespace` `std`

The source code can be found [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.5/a00850_source.html) for future reference

Comment: the source code already says this is "ISO/IEC TR 24733" so it's just a TR and not a C++ feature. There's no `decimal` namespace in C++ and no `decimal/decimal` header yet

Answer (score 0):

I've asked around, and I think I've solved the problem. The equivalent of `_Decimal64` in C is `__decfloat64` in C++.

I present an example which allows the interop of decimals in C and C++. It may look more complicated than necessary, but I wanted to demonstrate how one might use it in a real project.

Here are the files:

File dec.h:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <decimal/decimal>
typedef std::decimal::decimal64::__decfloat64 Num;
#else
typedef _Decimal64 Num;
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

Num get_num();
void print_num(Num n);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

File decc.c:

```
#include "dec.h"

Num get_num()
{
    return 0.2DD;
}
```

File deccc.cc:

```
#include <decimal/decimal>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> // for std::setprecision()

#include "dec.h"


void print_num(Num n)
{
    std::decimal::decimal64 d64(n);
    std::cout << std::setprecision(20) << std::decimal::decimal_to_float(d64) << std::endl;
    // Output is 0.20000000298023223877

}

int main()
{
    Num n = get_num();
    print_num(n);

    std::cout << ( 0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3) << std::endl; // false (0)
    std::cout << ( 0.1DD + 0.2DD == 0.3DD) << std::endl; // true (1)

    return 0;
}
```

File Makefile:

```
dec : decc.o deccc.o
        g++ decc.o deccc.o -o dec

decc.o : decc.c
        gcc -c decc.c

deccc.o : deccc.cc
        g++ -c deccc.cc

.PHONY : clean
clean :
rm -f *.o dec
```

You can find this files as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/blippy/139fb0f2dff8703b6eae8129509d0d14).

There does not seem to be any printing routines for decimals in the GNU compiler collection 6.3.1. I have my own ones that work to my satisfaction, so I am not too fussed at this stage. I think I saw a spec where the print directive for a decimal is a "D"; but again, it is not available in a released version.

The only output routine that GNU provides is if you first convert the decimal to a float, as in `std::cout << std::setprecision(20)  << std::decimal::decimal_to_float(d64) << std::endl;`. You can see that it is not ideal, as errors creep in the conversion. The actual output is 0.20000000298023223877.

The internal representation of the decimals seems to be correct, though. If we ask that age-old question: does `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3`, we see that in floats the exe returns `0` for false.

However, if we make the comparison `0.1DD + 0.2DD == 0.3DD` then the exe answers `1` for true.

Phew.

Comment: Use std::decimal::decimal_to_double, rather than std::decimal::decimal_to_float; otherwise you will lose several digits of precision.

Comment: **`_Decimal64` isn't a C type** until C23, before that it's just a GNU extension. And there's no `__decfloat64` in C++. Anything that begins with `__` is an extension of some compilers. Even `std::decimal::decimal64` isn't standard C++ type

Comment: @phuclv I agree that this isn't standard C++, but your comment "Anything that begins with `__` is an extension of some compilers" is wrong. `__cplusplus`, for one, is not an extension -- but more than that, the C++ standard libraries use `__` prefixes all the time in their implementations to avoid conflicts with user-defined code since all names are reserved. That doesn't make it an extension; it just means that it's logically not meant to be used directly.