# How to convert a std::decimal::decimal128 to string in C++

Tags: c++, string, decimal

I want to convert a `std::decimal::decimal128` into a `string` in C++. I have tried this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::decimal::decimal128 check1(0.1654689875468);
    string ee;  
    ee=std::to_string(check1);

    return 0;
}
```

but it gives an error. I have tried so many methods, yet no one works. Anyone have an idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"in C++"* Eh, no, this is not in C++ yet. Have you a reference for your particular implementation?

Comment: This is a TS for C++

Comment: @DeiDei I'm sorry, I didn't understand your response.

Comment: my ultimate goal is to print the content of the std::decimal::decimal128 to the user.

Comment: "it gives an error." You need to read the error mesaage and understand what it says. Sorry can't do that for you.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12865735/8161208) suggests that decimal support in gcc is implemented in terms of libdecnum.

Comment: `std::decimal` has not been added to any C++ standard yet.  As such, your answer will depend on the exact implementation and what paper it implements and how well it does.

Comment: Something like Integer.toString() in java?

Comment: @n.m. I have read the error message but from what I understand is that the "to_string" function can not be applied to decimal128

Comment: @VolodymyrLashko Yes, I have seen that answer but I couldn't figure how to apply it on my case.

Comment: @Yakk So, do you suggest using Boost instead?

Comment: @VidorVistrom Yes. I'm looking for something like that but to convert from decimal128 to string.

Comment: You should post the exact text of the error message as a part of your question but anyway. It looks like your compiler doesn't support decimas fully. Remember they are not a part of the C++ standars yet. You may be able to write your own to_string implementation using stringstream.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks for replying! I have tried the following:

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    std::decimal::decimal128 total(1.3265465468484);
    float a = 5.23;
    std::stringstream ta;
    std::stringstream tb;
    ta << a;
    tb << total;
    ta.precision(2);
    tb.precision(2);
    std::string out = "";
    out += ta.str() + "\n";
    out += tb.str() + "\n";


    return 0;


}
It works fine with float but not with decimal128.

Comment: I suggest you tell us the exact implementation you are using, and ideally which paper it is trying to implement.  C++ is way too vague.   Which compiler - not stated.  What version - not stated.  What flags used so that include works - not stated.  "C++" does not describe your problem, because this is not part of C++ yet.

Comment: @Yakk, sorry, I'm new so that's why I don't know much about c++. I'm using Netbeans IDE 8.2 on Windows 10. I'm also using MinGW with g++ compiler. The C++ standard is C++14.

Comment: What I want to do is to write the value of the Decimal128 variable on a text file. That's why I need to convert it to string. If I can write it without conversion that would solve the puzzle too.

Comment: any answer yet! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by creating the following function:

```
 std::string ToString(std::decimal::decimal128 dec)
{
    long double d(std::decimal::decimal128_to_double(dec));
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << std::scientific << std::setprecision(37) << d;
    return oss.str();
}
```

Later I can use it whenever I need it:

```
string name= ToString(std::decimal::decimal128_to_double(1.3246546787));
```

Thanks all for helping.

Comment: This loses precision awfully: `decimal128` contains 34 decimal digits, while common implementations of `double` are `binary64`, which can generally only round-trip 15 decimals. Even `long double` (even if done correctly, not as in the code here) would be insufficient: the native x87 80-bit format can generally round-trip 18 decimal digits only.